# CI for the expected value of the sum of two dependent normal RVs

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, finance

Let's consider 2 dependent, normally distributed R.V.s, $X_1$ and $X_2$. The means, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are known, as well the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Let's consider the following random variable: $Y = w_1$$X_1 +  w_2X_2$, where $w_1, w_2 \in [0,1]$ and $w_1 + w_2 = 1$. $w_1$ and $w_2$ are chosen in a way that the standard deviation of $Y$ is minimal.

Is there a best practice to build a confidence interval around $E[Y]$? We've been able to do it with bootstrap using matlab's: [botci](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootci.html) function, but we were wondering if there's an analytic solution.

A real world application of this scenario is the minimum variance portfolio of 2 risky assets, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the time series of the returns in a [CER](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/constantexpectedreturn.pdf) model.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, $Y$ is a gaussian RV, which makes things straightforward, and also the question pointless since the mean can be computed analytically: $E[Y] = w_1\mu_1 + w_2\mu_2$

tags:

Comment: onion: The random variable Y is normal with known mean E(Y)=w1mu1+w2mu2 and with known variance. Could you explain what is your question exactly?

Comment: @Did Is $Y$ normal even when $X_1$ and $X_2$ have different means?

Comment: @Did oh actually yes. The different means don't cause any trouble. But is it true also for dependent RVs?

Comment: Time for some fact checking on your part, it seems... Which sources do you use on normal random variables?

Comment: @DId You're right, it's still normal: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22879/linear-combination-of-two-dependent-multivariate-normal-random-variables

Comment: Thus: no question remaining?

Comment: @Did All clear thanks, no questions remaining.

Comment: Thus: close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Y is a gaussian RV, which makes things straightforward, and also the question pointless since the mean can be computed analytically: $E[Y]=w_1*μ\mu1+w_2\mu_2$